# Maven Error while generating sources for Hadoop

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, hadoop

Am facing error below while generating sources for Hadoop Trunk. The error states it cannot find Plugin **org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-maven-plugins:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT**. I tried to use 2.3.0 of hadoop-maven-plugins in pom to solve the problem. Below is the error.

```
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-maven-plugins:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-maven-plugins:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
    org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-maven-plugins:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-maven-plugins:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:140)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getPluginDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:142)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:261)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:185)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecution(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:152)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecutions(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:139)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:129)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.BuilderCommon.resolveBuildPlan(BuilderCommon.java:92)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
    Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not find artifact org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-maven-plugins:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:538)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:216)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:193)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:286)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:136)
        ... 25 more
    Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-maven-plugins:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:528)
        ... 29 more
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

Am solving this by manually going into project pom.xml in the error and including the plugin version for **hadoop-maven-plugins** to **2.3.0** in each hadoop-* project.

Can I do this to all the projects to use this version ?

Is there a better way to solve this problem ?

P.S:
Why am trying to generate sources is Am facing similar problem mentioned in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/jenkinsci-dev/9S_Dgv2pnkM/qAkpifegDR8J while loading maven project into eclipse.

**EDIT1** : Fixed temporarily by manually changing the following files in trunk(http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/trunk/).

```
./hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/pom.xml
./hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/pom.xml
./hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/contrib/bkjournal/pom.xml
./hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/pom.xml
./hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-server/hadoop-yarn-server-common/pom.xml
./hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-server/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager/pom.xml
./hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common/pom.xml
./hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs/pom.xml
```

Comment: post your pom.xml too

Comment: One of the pom.xml is available at 
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/trunk/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/pom.xml

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As per **BUILDING.txt** in the trunk, execute **mvn install** to generate the snapshot version of hadoop-maven-plugins.

2 commands from trunk solved the problem :

```
$ cd hadoop-maven-plugins
$ mvn install
```